# How do I update S3 object to Infrequent Access using Carrierwave-Aws

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave

I uploaded a file using Carrierwave + Carrierwave-aws to Amazon S3, now I want to update the Storage-Class of a Object to Standard Infrequent Access, how can I do with Carrierwave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Carrierwave uses Fog for interacting with AWS S3. To configure or change the storage class you have to add that update to the `carrierwave/lib/carrierwave/storage/file.rb` file in [Carrierwave-Aws](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/file.rb).

Check out https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb used to change or configure the storage class for S3. Below parameter sets or changes the storage class for S3.

```
attribute :storage_class
```

Comment: So you have to add the edit to this file https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/aws_file.rb